# SCSS / Angular : updating the value of a global variable not working

Tags: angular, sass, scss-mixins

Here is the reproduction :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kkmboa

I would like to update the value of a SCSS variable so that I can configure my theme.

**index.scss**

```scss
$color: black;

@mixin setup() {
  $color: green !global;
}

@function color() {
  @return $color;
}
```

**global_styles.scss**

```scss
@use 'index';
@include index.setup();
```

**component.scss**

```scss
@use '../index.scss';

p {
  color: index.color();
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Using this code, the variable `$color` should become green. But that's not the case. From what I assume, the component SCSS is compiled before the global style, hence the issue.

What would be the solution to this problem ?

Comment: What's the point of having a setup function and calling it from global_styles ?

Comment: This is an example, but the purpose is to make it into a library